# Can't Use HttpHeaders and WithCredentials Option Together

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have a .net5 WebApi which requires the credentials to be sent from my Angular application. Everything is ok when I use an HttpInterceptor to specify that all my requests will include the credentials in every call, but if I put `withCredentials` option together with any `HtpHeaders` the requests don't pass the CORS validation.

Here is how my interceptor look like (which work fine):

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HttpInterceptService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    }));
  }
}
```

But if the call is made as below, the CORS validation don't pass:

```js
public apiCall(): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.get(API_URL, {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'my-auth-token'
    })
  });
}
```

CORS error (when I use withCredentials together with headers):

[image: CORS error]

But if I remove the headers, everything work fine:

```js
public apiCall(): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.get(API_URL, {
    withCredentials: true
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you using the proxy configuration to connect your app with your API?

Comment: No, how can I use the proxy configuration?

Comment: check this resource https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server, your error might be related to it.

Comment: You have to allow `http://localhost:4200` from you backend. There is nothing to do with angular. Make sure you have added this headers in backend api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: The origin is allowed in the backend. The error comes when I use the withCredentials and headers options of the HttpClient together, if I remove the headers the call work fine. What I can see is that I can't use both options at the same time.